# Create shell alias with semi-colon character

Tags: macos, zsh, zsh-alias

I've noticed that I have a tendency to mistype `ls` as `;s`, so I decided that I should just create an alias so that instead of throwing an error, it just runs the command I mean.

However, knowing that the semi-colon character has a meaning in shell scripts/commands, is there any way to allow me to create an alias with that the semi-colon key? I've tried the following to no avail:

```
alias ;s=ls
alias ";s"=ls
alias \;=ls
```

Is it possible to use the semi-colon as a character in a shell alias? And how do I do so in ZSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First and foremost: **Consider solving your problem differently - fighting the shell grammar this way is asking for trouble.**
- As far as I can tell, **while you can *define* such a command - albeit not with an *alias* - the only way to *call* it is *quoted*, e.g. as `\;s` - which defeats the purpose**; read on for technical details.

  - **An *alias* won't work**: while `zsh` allows you to *define* it (which, arguably, it shouldn't), the very mechanism that would be required to *call* it - *quoting* - is also the very mechanism that *bypasses* aliases and thus *prevents* invocation.
  - You can, however, **define a *function* (`zsh` only) or a *script in your `$PATH`*** (works in `zsh` as well as in `bash`, `ksh`, and `dash`), **as long as you invoke it *quoted*** (e.g., as `\;s` or `';s'` or `";s"`), which **defeats the purpose**.

For the record, here are the command definitions, but, again, they can only be invoked *quoted*.

Function (works in `zsh` only; place in an initialization file such as `~/.zshrc`):

```
 ';s'() { ls "$@" }
```

Executable script `;s` (works in `dash`, `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`; place in a directory in your `$PATH`):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 ls "$@"
```

Comment: So the long and short of it is that I can't alias the raw `;s` to `ls` to work around my incorrect typing?

Comment: You can't define an _alias_, but you can define a _function_ (or even an executable script in your `$PATH`).

Comment: But I can't call that function without quoting/escaping the semi-colon character?

Comment: @DamonSwayn: Yes - I was so focused on finding a _technical_ solution that I didn't realize that having to quote on invocation completely defeats the purpose - I've updated the answer accordingly. It comes back to fighting the shell grammar; I don't think it's worth doing.